# Mysql Error al crear clave foránea pese a tener las mismas propiedades

Tags: mysql, xampp, tabla-dinámica

Mysql me está tirando un error 1452 al intentar crear la clave foránea entre edad_id de la tabla Productos y el id de la tabla Edades:

[image: Vista tabla Productos con detalle del error al crear el vínculo con la tabla Edades]

edad_id en la tabla Productos es:

- Not null
- Predeterminado: ninguno
- int unsigned
- Index

el id en la tabla Edades es:

- Not null
- Predeterminado: ninguno
- int unsigned
- Primary key
- Auto increment

y edad en la tabla Edades es:

- Enum
- Not null
- Predeterminado: ninguno

Al intentar hacer la relación la configuración es:

- ON DELETE: NO ACTION
- ON UPDATE: CASCADE

Aún así al querer vincular Edades Id con Productos edad_id no me está dejando (si es al revés sí, pero necesito que sea desde Edades a Productos como en el caso de las demás tablas de arriba)
Borré y volví a armar la tabla en caso de que hubiera configurado mal algo, pero el error persiste.

Algo que noté pero no sé si tiene algo que ver es que al ver la estructura de la tabla Edades no están apareciendo los datos cargados del campo edad con Enum (Todas las edades, Niños; Adultos):

[image: Estructura Tabla Edades]

Alguna idea de cuál podría ser el error?
Saludos!

Comment: Hola. En vez de tantas imágenes muestra los CREATE TABLE de las tablas implicadas y el mensaje de error, todo como texto. No se entiende bien si es que una de las columnas es `enum` y la otra es `int` en cuyo caso es normal que dé error porque las columnas deben ser exactamente del mismo tipo y tamaño.